# Upsampling of a signal

Tags: filtering, upsampling

A low-passed signal, bandwidth  limited to 4KHz is originally sampled 10 KHz. If I want to resample it at 20 KHz, I take these steps. Are these correct? Am I missing an step?

1. First we need to filter the signal. Since the bandwidth is limited to 4KHz, we need a LPF with cutoff freq. of 4KHz.
2. Now we need to upsample it at 20KHz. We do this by simply inserting zeros between original samples.
3. I am skeptical here whether we need another LPF here or not. If so, should the cutoff freq. be 10KHz? Or 4 KHz suffices?

Comment: If you are already limited to 4(kHz) of signal bandwidth, what good will applying a LPF with a cutoff freq of 4(kHz) do? Won't you just get the same thing back? Also, what does the spectrum of your signal look like after zero insertion? Do you see any replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First we need to filter the signal. Since the bandwidth is limited to 4KHz, we need a LPF with cutoff freq. of 4KHz.

If the signal is already bandlimited, there is no need for this filter.

> Now we need to upsample it at 20KHz. We do this by simply inserting zeros between original samples.

Correct. That's the first step of upsampling.

> I am skeptical here whether we need another LPF here or not. If so, should the cutoff freq. be 10KHz? Or 4 KHz suffices?

You do need a lowpass filter here. Inserting zeros results in a periodic repetition of the original spectrum. You need a filter to remove the mirror spectrum between 5 kHz and 10 kHz. The cutoff frequency needs to be around 4k kHz but below 5 kHz.

In practice, the choice of this lowpass filter is the most tricky problem. It requires a complicated trade off between passband ripple, stopband steepness and attenuation which in turn determines residual aliasing. There are also phase distortion, time domain ringing, causality and implementation considerations like memory, CPU, latency, real-time etc. All of these depend a lot on your data and the requirements of your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

First insert the zeros, then filter. The filter's cutoff is set to the original Nyquist of 5 kHz, but it's designed to run at a sampling rate of 20 kHz.